# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on an old MacBook Pro 2,2

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, macbook-pro

I have an old MacBook Pro 2,2 that I am trying to squeeze more life out of by installing Linux on it. I cannot get it to boot from a CD or a USB stick. I tried both Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit and Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. I also have reFit installed.

[image]

Comment: Well, what errors do you have? How are you trying to boot from CD or USB? How did you created those CDs or USB sticks?

Comment: Have you tried booting [MacPup](http://www.macpup.org/) as a 'proof of concept'?

Comment: The main error is "no operating system found".  I burned the iso's with Windows 10 to make the CDs, and I used Rufus to create the bootable USB stick.

I have not checked out MacPup...

Comment: Added a screenshot to original psot.